# Complex DynamoDB update statement

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, upsert

I have a dynamodb table "metas" which has a field of `id`, `time`, `ttl`.

I want to upsert an item with `id` X. The updated field is `time` and only update if the new value is bigger than the old value (update it to new value). If the field doesn't exist on the database yet, I want this field to be **current unix timestamp**. At the same time, every upsert will change the `ttl` of that item.

How can this be done within a single Update statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
    --table-name myTable \
    --key '{"Id": {"S": "X"}}' \
    --update-expression "SET #ttl = :ttl" \
    --condition-expression "#ttl < :ttl" \
    --expression-attribute-values '{":ttl"{"N":"4849304759"}} \
    --expression-attribute-names '{"#ttl":"ttl"}'
```